# How to add Revit toposolid from GIS KMZ data?

Tags: contour, kmz, topography, revit

I am new to Revit but I am having trouble importing GIS data (KMZ format) into a toposolid. The KMZ file contains contours, parcel and building footprint information. I have tried several tools and tutorials but no luck so far. Here are some of the things I've tried:

- [Designbotic Terrain](https://youtu.be/YuHHYpUbM9Y?si=9MJ7GqY9ra7kLkIV)
- [Creating 3D toposurfaces from imported DWG files in Revit](https://www.autodesk.com/support/technical/article/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Creating-toposurfaces-from-imported-DWG-files.html)
- [Create a Toposolid from Imported Data](https://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2024/ENU/?guid=GUID-A1E1DE84-29AE-4B99-B377-091C0AC45249)
- [CADMAPPER](https://cadmapper.com/)

I havent tried these yet because I wanted to see if it could be done without using plugins first but as a last resort I'll try one of these if I cant get anything else to work.

- [GE-Terrain for Revit](https://www.analistgroup.com/en/ge-terrain-for-revit)
- [CADToEarth™ for Autodesk® Revit®](https://youtu.be/-jmNiu83Dic?si=VHibwyY8D2d6IxVI)